# How to display a Google Map on value change in a HTML select

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm working on a project and I'm stuck: I want to use the selected city from a drop down box to then display a Google Map of that city.

Here is the code I've been working on, but it isn't working. I've added in the the variables for each location, so that creating the maps will be simple. The biggest issue I am having is getting it to read the selected option, so that when I choose Philadelphia in the drop down it will then choose the map for Philadelphia.

```
<form>
            <select id="cities" onchange="initMap()" >
                <option  value="penn" selected>Select a City</option>
                <option  value="phi">Philadelphia</option>
                <option  value="pit">Pittsburgh</option>
                <option  value="har">Harrisburg</option>
            </select>

</form>
<div id="map"></div>
function initMap() {
        var penn = {lat: 41, lng: -77};
        var phi = {lat: 39.952583, lng: -75.165222};
        var pit = {lat: 40.440624, lng: -79.995888};
        var har = {lat: 40.263680, lng: -76.890739};

        if (document.getElementById("cities").value = 'penn') {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
            zoom: 7,
            center: penn
        }); 
        }

        else if (document.getElementById("cities").value = 'phi') {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
            zoom: 10,
            center: phi
        }); 
        }

        else if (document.getElementById("cities").value = 'pit') {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
            zoom: 10,
            center: pit
        }); 
         }

        else if (document.getElementById("cities").value = 'har') {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
            zoom: 13,
            center: har
        }); 
        }
    }


</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAJuIBH_cjgQuJE7HUUE1EA0jbF176yZXA&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: You should use `===` or `==` on conditions. Not `=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `===` or `==` on if/else. Not `=`

```
if ( document.getElementById("cities").value === 'penn' ) {
     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
          zoom: 7,
          center: penn
     }); 
}
```

`=` is assignment

`==` is comparison

Comment: I'm still not very good when it comes to my JavaScript coding, so thank you for the very quick response and huge help. I updated my code with this and it worked great! Thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help. :)